# Meteor.js - protecting template with a password

Tags: meteor

My Meteor.js app is suppose to contain password protection feature. Registered user can set a password to a certain object in Collection, and public users should then authenticate using this password to access the object template.

I wonder what would be the best approach?

Ideas so far:

--Generate a unique auth token and save it to the Session object on the client side. Use this token on the client to identify if the password form should be displayed instead of the actual object template

--Original password is available only on the server side, where it is properly salted and peppered

Questions:

--I need a server side API where client could query the password for the current object that user tries to access. How do you do this in Meteor?

--Defining the password per object and storing it with the object. This is really confusing - the password needs to be sent to the server, not stored on the client, then salted and stored on server along with the protected object.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing would be to

Have a template on the client that is visible (the raw HTML but without any sensitive data), e.g If its a private area, perhaps links to the download or the data concerning the account.

The second is to use a scoped `Meteor.publish` function. So you have the (lets say download link) stored in a collection on the server then you publish it in a way like:

Server side js:

```
var DownloadLinks = new Meteor.Collection("downloads");

Meteor.publish("collection", function() {
    //Only a logged in user will get the data
    if(this.userId) return DownloadLinks
});
```

Your client side:

You could install a package such as `accounts-ui` and `accounts-password` to get started with quickly

Your HTML

```
<!-- Buttons to log in -->
{{loginButtons}}

{{#if currentUser}}
    <h1>Private Section</h1> - <p>Only visible if you're logged in</p>
{{/if}}
```

Your client side js

```
DownloadLinks = new Meteor.Collection("downloads");

Meteor.subscribe("collection");
```

So here the user would only get access to stuff inside the `DownloadLinks` collection if they're signed in. The 'private section' would only be visible if you're logged in. If a hacker tried to read it they still can't access the download links since the server wouldn't publish them until the user is signed in.

Comment: I have an online example of the process @Tarang describes here:  http://roles.meteor.com   Source code is available here: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: Thanks, this is a great comment and a good direction. However in addition to the registered users and roles - there should be option to share certain collection objects protected by password. So the object creator creates password, and the user who tries to access the object need to enter the same password. Something like Flickr's password protected photosets.

Comment: You can do that by altering your publish function to however you want it. The publish function determines the data available to the client so you could decide depending on what your mongo query is